# neo4j 4.4 community scalability

Tags: neo4j

My neo4j community database reach near 1TB and I have only 64GB of RAM , can I use fabric to scale the database horizontally and share the load between different servers or fabric is only for enterprise licensed neo4j versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Getting Started with Neo4j Fabric Blog](https://neo4j.com/blog/getting-started-with-neo4j-fabric/):

> Fabric is an Enterprise Only feature, meaning it is not available for the Neo4j Community Edition.

The [licensing FAQ](https://neo4j.com/licensing/) says:

> Neo4j Enterprise Edition is also available for free for a number of uses

You could state your use case and ask them for a free Enterprise license maybe.
The community edition doesn't have an option for scaling/sharding.